# insert db values to a .js file laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

i have a view,

```
<div class="square_box col-xs-7 text-right">
      <span>Views Today</span>

  <div class="number" id="myTargetElement1"></div>
                            </div>
```

so i want to pass some values from my database to this .js file the value 90 for instance i want to fetch it from the database

```
 var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement1", 12.52, 90, 0, 6, options);
    demo.start();
```

please help me out cause am stuck trying to figure out how to use the php query script inside a js file found in the public folder

Comment: Can't be done.  You need to include the JS in a blade template using a `<script>` tag, or you need to fetch the data using an ajax request from inside the JS file.

Comment: What is your db query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the html tag attribute to store the values and then retrieve it in your JavaScript file.
HTML file:

```
<div class="square_box col-xs-7 text-right">
      <span>Views Today</span>

  <div class="number" data-value={{$value}} id="myTargetElement1"></div>
                            </div>
```

JS file:.

```
<script>
    var value = $('#myTargetElement1').attr('data-value');
    var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement1", 12.52, value, 0, 6, options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use AJAX to fetch your data into your JS code and then use it.

Or you can simply fetch your result from db and pass it to your view.

```
$value = DB::table('your_table')->get();
return view('some_view', [ 'value' => $value ]);
```

Then simply just echo it out using {{ blade }} in your view file

```
<script>
    var demo = new CountUp("myTargetElement1", 12.52, {{ $value }}, 0, 6, options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to use ajax to call a view and display that view inside of your html.

Here is a very crude example.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/your/view",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#myTargetElement1" ).append( html );
  });
```